# How to reuse laravel controller code in custom command

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have controller file that has a function login() that logs in(authenticates and returns a token) to some third party portal. Now i want to reuse that controller function in a custom command. Please suggest how to do so. My controller file looks like this-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class mmt extends Controller {
public function login() {
 //code to login to third party portal
 // returns a token after successful login
}
```

my custom command file located in app/Console/Commands looks like this-

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
class RcvSurveyEmails extends Command {
   protected $signature = 'RcvSurveyEmails:name';
   protected $description = 'command description here';
   public function handle(){
  //I need to use the login() function here and get the token.
}
?>
```

I search online for similar solution but could not fine any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this In two Ways:

**Method 1**
`Use Trait`

```
trait LoginTrait{
   public function Login(){
   //put your code here
   }
}
```

And After that you can use your function inside your class like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class mmt extends Controller {
  use LoginTrait;//login is now available inside your class

  //rest of your codes
}
```

And In Your Command It's Going to be like below:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
class RcvSurveyEmails extends Command {
   use LoginTrait;//login Function is now avaiable inside your Command and you can call it
   protected $signature = 'RcvSurveyEmails:name';
   protected $description = 'command description here';

   public function handle(){
   login();//login function
   }
}
```

**Method 2**

In case that your controller class doesn't have any special `constructor` you can create an instance from your controller inside your `command` and then call your method like below:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\mmt;
class RcvSurveyEmails extends Command {
   protected $signature = 'RcvSurveyEmails:name';
   protected $description = 'command description here';

   public function handle(){
   $controller = new mmt();//your controller name
   $controller->login();
   }
}
```

Comment: you have to put use at the beginning of your file...
like this: use App\Http\Controllers\mmt;